# Intent makes my app crash

Tags: android, xml

At the moment I'm writing an App which Scans NFC Tags and tells you what's written on the Tag.

But now I have a problem. I wrote a Intent into the Menu, so that from the Menu you can get to that Scan-Page. But when I pasted the code that Scans the NFC Tags, the Intent suddenly Stoped working.

I can install the App without a Problem and there is no Error, but When I click onto the Button in The Menu that should bring me to the Page on which I scan NFC Tags, the App just crashes.

I really do not Know where the error is, and I would be very glad if you could help me.

I will provide the code I have so far below:

```
Menu with Intents:

    package com.example.kristian.nfcproject;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class nfc_menu extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_nfc_menu);
        getSupportActionBar().hide();


        Button buttonLogout = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonLogout);
        Button buttonProfil = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonProfil);
        Button buttonAssets = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonAssets);
        Button buttonNfcid = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonNfcid);
        Button buttonNfcscan = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonNfcscan);

        buttonLogout.setOnClickListener(
                new Button.OnClickListener()
                {
                    public void onClick(View v)
                    {
                        Intent logoutI = new Intent(v.getContext(), MainActivity.class);
                        startActivity(logoutI);
                    }
                }
        );


        buttonProfil.setOnClickListener(
                new Button.OnClickListener()
                {
                    public void onClick(View v)
                    {
                        Intent meinprofilI = new Intent(v.getContext(), meinprofil.class);
                        startActivity(meinprofilI);
                    }
                }
        );


        buttonAssets.setOnClickListener(
                new Button.OnClickListener()
                {
                    public void onClick(View v)
                    {
                        Intent assetsI = new Intent(v.getContext(), meineassets.class);
                        startActivity(assetsI);
                    }
                }
        );


        buttonNfcid.setOnClickListener(
                new Button.OnClickListener()
                {
                    public void onClick(View v)
                    {
                        Intent nfcidI = new Intent(v.getContext(), nfcidhinzu.class);
                        startActivity(nfcidI);
                    }
                }
        );


        buttonNfcscan.setOnClickListener(
                new Button.OnClickListener()
                {
                    public void onClick(View v)
                    {
                        Intent nfcscannI = new Intent(v.getContext(), nfctagscann.class);
                        startActivity(nfcscannI);
                    }
                }
        );
    }
}
```

The NFC Scan Activity:

```
  package com.example.kristian.nfcproject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.nfc.NdefMessage;
import android.nfc.NdefRecord;
import android.nfc.NfcAdapter;
import android.nfc.Tag;
import android.nfc.tech.Ndef;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.content.IntentFilter.MalformedMimeTypeException;

import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;




import com.example.kristian.nfcproject.R;

import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class nfctagscann extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView text;
    NfcAdapter nfcAdapter;
    public static final String MIME_TEXT_PLAIN = "text/plain";
    public static final String TAG = "NfcDemo";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_nfcidhinzu);
        getSupportActionBar().hide();

        text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
        nfcAdapter = NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(this);

        if (nfcAdapter == null) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "This Device doesn't support NFC", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            finish();
        }

        if (!nfcAdapter.isEnabled()) {
            text.setText("Please enable NFC in your settings.");
        } else {
            text.setText(R.string.explanation);
        }
        handleIntent(getIntent());
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        /**
         * It's important, that the activity is in the foreground (resumed). Otherwise
         * an IllegalStateException is thrown.
         */
        setupForegroundDispatch(this, nfcAdapter);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        /**
         * Call this before onPause, otherwise an IllegalArgumentException is thrown as well.
         */
        stopForegroundDispatch(this, nfcAdapter);

        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
        /**
         * This method gets called, when a new Intent gets associated with the current activity instance.
         * Instead of creating a new activity, onNewIntent will be called. For more information have a look
         * at the documentation.
         *
         * In our case this method gets called, when the user attaches a Tag to the device.
         */
        handleIntent(intent);
    }

    public static void setupForegroundDispatch(final Activity activity, NfcAdapter adapter) {
        final Intent intent = new Intent(activity.getApplicationContext(), activity.getClass());
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);

        final PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(activity.getApplicationContext(), 0, intent, 0);

        IntentFilter[] filters = new IntentFilter[1];
        String[][] techList = new String[][]{};

        // Notice that this is the same filter as in our manifest.
        filters[0] = new IntentFilter();
        filters[0].addAction(NfcAdapter.ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED);
        filters[0].addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
        try {
            filters[0].addDataType(MIME_TEXT_PLAIN);
        } catch (MalformedMimeTypeException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Check your mime type.");
        }

        adapter.enableForegroundDispatch(activity, pendingIntent, filters, techList);
    }

    public static void stopForegroundDispatch(final Activity activity, NfcAdapter adapter) {
        adapter.disableForegroundDispatch(activity);
    }

    private void handleIntent(Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        if (NfcAdapter.ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED.equals(action)) {

            String type = intent.getType();
            if (MIME_TEXT_PLAIN.equals(type)) {

                Tag tag = intent.getParcelableExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG);
                new NdefReaderTask().execute(tag);

            } else {
                Log.d(TAG, "Wrong mime type: " + type);
            }
        } else if (NfcAdapter.ACTION_TECH_DISCOVERED.equals(action)) {

            // In case we would still use the Tech Discovered Intent
            Tag tag = intent.getParcelableExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG);
            String[] techList = tag.getTechList();
            String searchedTech = Ndef.class.getName();

            for (String tech : techList) {
                if (searchedTech.equals(tech)) {
                    new NdefReaderTask().execute(tag);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private class NdefReaderTask extends AsyncTask<Tag, Void, String> {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Tag... params) {
            Tag tag = params[0];

            Ndef ndef = Ndef.get(tag);
            if (ndef == null) {
                // NDEF is not supported by this Tag.
                return null;
            }

            NdefMessage ndefMessage = ndef.getCachedNdefMessage();

            NdefRecord[] records = ndefMessage.getRecords();
            for (NdefRecord ndefRecord : records) {
                if (ndefRecord.getTnf() == NdefRecord.TNF_WELL_KNOWN && Arrays.equals(ndefRecord.getType(), NdefRecord.RTD_TEXT)) {
                    try {
                        return readText(ndefRecord);
                    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "Unsupported Encoding", e);
                    }
                }
            }
            return null;
        }

        private String readText(NdefRecord record) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
        /*
         * See NFC forum specification for "Text Record Type Definition" at 3.2.1
         *
         * http://www.nfc-forum.org/specs/
         *
         * bit_7 defines encoding
         * bit_6 reserved for future use, must be 0
         * bit_5..0 length of IANA language code
         */

            byte[] payload = record.getPayload();

            // Get the Text Encoding
            String textEncoding = ((payload[0] & 128) == 0) ? "UTF-8" : "UTF-16";

            // Get the Language Code
            int languageCodeLength = payload[0] & 0063;

            // String languageCode = new String(payload, 1, languageCodeLength, "US-ASCII");
            // e.g. "en"

            // Get the Text
            return new String(payload, languageCodeLength + 1, payload.length - languageCodeLength - 1, textEncoding);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            if (result != null) {
                text.setText("NFC INHALT" + result);
            }
        }



    }
}
```

Before Pasting this pre written code into the App the Intent worked fine, now when I click the button to get to the Scan Activity the app just crashes.

I appreciate every kind of help :)

Log:

```
03-19 18:34:27.669 22810-22810/com.example.kristian.nfcproject E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 Process: com.example.kristian.nfcproject, PID: 22810
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.kristian.nfcproject/com.example.kristian.nfcproject.nfctagscann}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Already attached
     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2924)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2985)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap14(ActivityThread.java)
     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1635)
     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6692)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1468)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1358)
  Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Already attached
     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.attachController(FragmentManager.java:3146)
     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.attachHost(FragmentController.java:95)
     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreate(FragmentActivity.java:283)
     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onCreate(AppCompatActivity.java:84)
     at com.example.kristian.nfcproject.nfctagscann.onCreate(nfctagscann.java:42)
     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6912)
     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1126)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2877)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2985) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap14(ActivityThread.java) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1635) 
     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6692) 
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1468) 
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1358)
```

Comment: Can you paste the log?

Comment: Pasted it in the question.